# Google Analytic on Ecommerce Tracking is not showing anything

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics, e-commerce

I read the document for Google Analytic on Ecommerce Tracking.  I simply followed its instruction, I copied and pasted on testing page before I can do it on lives site.  My issue is that I was not seeing anything on Ecommerce Tracking even though I followed its example.  Is anyone able to help me out, please? Thanks.

Here is the Google Analytic Ecommerce document: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-87205702-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('require', 'ecommerce');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
      'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
      'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
      'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
      'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
    });
    ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
```

Yes, I enabled on both "Enable Ecommerce" and "Enhanced Ecommerce Settings."
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to send between  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction' and ga('ecommerce:send');

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'Fluffy Pink Bunnies',    // Product name. Required.
  'sku': 'DD23444',                 // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Party Toys',         // Category or variation.
  'price': '11.99',                 // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                   // Quantity.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I just added that and it's showing up now!